# Kusto if Array contains array then return no results

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I want to write kusto query that should basically return no results if three records are present in the variable. Here is an example:

```
    let someValues = datatable (name: string)
    [
     "111",
     "222",
     "333",
    ];

// my query
```

So if the `someValues` variable contains all the three strings - "111", "222", "333" then my query should return no results. If it contains only 2 of them "111", "222" then it should just return false. If it contains 1 of them "222" then also it should return false. But if it contains all three strings "111", "222", "333" then the query should not return any results.

Here is my attempt but it doesn't work.

```
let someValues = datatable (name: string)
[
 "111",
 "222",
 "333",
];
someValues
| summarize make_set(name)
| where set_name contains "111" and set_name contains "222" and set_name contains "333" // this doesn't work because it outputs 1 row
```

Here is an equivalent C# program for that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> s = new List<string>() {"111", "222", "333"};
    if (s.Contains("111") && s.Contains("222") && s.Contains("333"))
        return; // no results
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False"); // prints false
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like over complication of logic that should be done by whomever is calling the query

Comment: We are setting up an alert in azure. If the query returns rows then alert will be sent. If the query doesn't return results then no alert will be sent. And when three rows are in the list then 0 rows should be returned by the query, so no alert should be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let someValues = datatable (name: string)
[
 "111",
 "222",
 "333"
];
let values = dynamic(["111", "222", "333"]);
someValues
| summarize make_set(name)
| project   diff_is_empty_set = array_length(set_difference(values, set_name)) == 0
| where     not(diff_is_empty_set)
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WOQQ7CIBBF9yTcYdIVJC5su9P0Gm5MQ7COigI1MNXUeHhBjC6EzWR4/30sEsTR4UbbCSN0sNeU7s4iCK8driBSMP4oOdtyBlVd19UiD03TlKFt24qzfs2ZTa7b1zOnuBnEtkQ+gYL3MtG/Vs6eECfndDAPBKcvqCLSu17mt2sYzzgQAOzN4aBMVOiuNGcoFekQ9Kws+iOdRFqpDGFAP6Aov1lAXr91EroOlll6PyUG8vEjiT+xfAG6BBPSGQEAAA==)